# MySQL SUM each Distinct Client_ID

Tags: php, mysql

Goal is to create a top ten list of returning clients. I have a "projects" table that also has a Client_ID for each project.

What I need is for the SQL query to return the top ten results for the Client_ID's that appear the most in the projects table.

I've tried this:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT Client_ID) AS 'Top Clients' FROM projects;
```

But truthfully I am just not sure how I can do this.

thanks for any help!

Comment: Use `JOIN` query with two table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this question [MySQL: Count occurrences of distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

```
SELECT Client_ID, COUNT(*) as TopClient FROM projects GROUP BY Client_ID ORDER BY TopClient DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Does this do the trick?