# Select Count of ip and Count of DISTINCT ip in same query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, distinct

I have a table structure like this:

```
TABLE NAME : counter

id  |        datetime       |  url  | ip
-------------------------------------------
1   |2013-04-12 13:27:09    | url1  | ip01
2   |2013-04-13 10:55:43    | url2  | ip02
3   |2013-04-14 11:14:12    | url1  | ip03
4   |2013-04-15 23:23:55    | url2  | ip04
5   |2013-05-02 08:34:44    | url1  | ip03
```

With a smart `SELECT` query, I want to fetch 3 columns that are:

```
Distinct URL    |    count of ip            |    count of distinct ip
                |    for each distinct url  |    for each distinct url  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
url1            |    3                      |    2    
url2            |    2                      |    2
```

I came up with my query below [by the help of this solution in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values) which gives me the first 2 columns that I need:

```
SELECT url, COUNT(*) AS total_ip FROM counter GROUP BY url ORDER BY total_ip DESC
```

But how can I add the 3rd column also into my query?

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned yourself, you can use `DISTINCT` keyword to get distinct `URL`s. Use `COUNT` to get count of `IP` and `COUNT(DISTINCT ID)` to get distinct `IP` for each `URL`s

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT URL AS D_URL
      ,COUNT(IP) AS IP
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT IP) AS D_IP
FROM counter
GROUP BY URL
```

Output:

```
╔═══════╦════╦══════╗
║ D_URL ║ IP ║ D_IP ║
╠═══════╬════╬══════╣
║ url1  ║  3 ║    2 ║
║ url2  ║  2 ║    2 ║
╚═══════╩════╩══════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40043/2)

Comment: Sometimes I wonder what's going through people's heads when the answer is almost verbatim what they asked in the question. "Count of distinct IP" => `COUNT(DISTINCT IP)`

Comment: @Barmar - Yeah he almost describe everything what he want.