# How to look at the result of a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL Query, although it is executing, but how should i verify if it is giving me the desired result. 
For example: My query

```
$query3 = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(uid)) AS `num` 
           FROM `user_info` 
           WHERE date(starttime)='2011-10-10'";
```

In the above query i am trying to count the number of distinct `user ID's(uid)` from the table named `user-info`where `date` is 2011-10-10.

How should i display the count which is calculated for the given date?.I need to know it and perform some further operations on it!

Comment: How are you displaying any values right now?

Comment: @juergend: I assume that when OP could run the query with either distinct or count(*) but when he tried both at the same time it stopped running.  The rest of the query seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query3 = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid) AS `num` 
           FROM `user_info` 
           WHERE date(starttime)='2011-10-10'";


$result = mysql_query($query3);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['num'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid) AS `num` 
FROM `user_info` 
WHERE date(starttime)='2011-10-10'
```

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337092/select-count-of-ip-and-count-of-distinct-ip-in-same-query?lq=1) goes into some details about how `count` and `count(distinct ...)` work.  With just `count`, there is a hidden/assumed function of `count(all ... )` actually happening (it's just the default value).  If you want to only count distinct things, switch it  to the non-default and do the `count(distinct ...)` instead.  I didn't know it existed for my first 6 months of writing sql or so...

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable sing the result...

```
SET @userVar=SELECT 
                COUNT(DISTINCT uid) 
              FROM 
                user_info 
              WHERE 
                DATE(starttime)='2011-10-10';
```

Then you can use that variable in your next operation or query.

Comment: looks like @gloomy.penguin got the same answer, his answer is useful if you want to get the result back, my answer allows you to then use that result in another query.