# Frequency list of each column in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have table that looks like this:

```
r01 r02 r03 r04
1   2   X   X
1   2   X   1
X   1   2   1
X   2   2   2
1   2   1   X
1   1   1   2
1   X   1   1
1   2   X   1
2   2   X   2
```

And I would like to get a frequency array list for each *column* (not row), similar to `array_count_values()`. Like

```
r01: 1 => 6, X => 2, 2 => 1
r02: 1 => 2, X => 1, 2 => 6
r03: 1 => 3, X => 4, 2 => 2
r04: 1 => 4, X => 2, 2 => 3
```

Is it possible to to with one or a few mysql questions? I have not come up with and idea. The only solution I has is to get all data to PHP and then have a data array and just add a one to corresponding counter for each row.

I can have 100->20000 rows. So I would like to have a mysql solution that scales better that a PHP solution.

-- Edit

I was displaying a simplified table structure but I think I need to show the full table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tips_rows` (
  `row_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `r01` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  `r02` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  `r03` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  `r04` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  `r05` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  `r06` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  `r07` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  `r08` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  `r09` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  `r10` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  `r11` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  `r12` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  `r13` enum('1','X','2') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`row_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And tips_rows contains all combinations of the values. (1,6 million rows) And to this I have a link table connection user to tips_rows, ´tips_rows_users´

So this link table would hold for a number of users a data set of 100-10000 row_id for each user.

I have found one solution base on other stackoverflow googling. Maybe not the purest query but it works and is fast.

```
 SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN r01 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r11,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r01 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r1X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r01 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r12,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r02 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r21,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r02 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r2X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r02 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r22,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r03 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r31,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r03 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r3X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r03 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r32,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r04 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r41,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r04 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r4X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r04 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r42,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r05 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r51,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r05 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r5X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r05 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r52,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r06 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r61,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r06 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r6X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r06 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r62,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r07 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r71,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r07 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r7X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r07 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r72,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r08 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r81,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r08 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r8X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r08 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r82,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r09 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r91,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r09 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r9X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r09 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r92,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r10 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r101,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r10 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r10X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r10 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r102,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r11 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r111,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r11 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r11X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r11 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r112,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r12 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r121,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r12 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r12X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r12 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r122,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r13 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r131,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r13 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r13X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r13 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r132
    FROM `tips_rows` AS r
    INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id)
    WHERE user__id='{userid}'
```

This will give me one result row as

```
r11 r1X r12 r21 r2X r22 r31 r3X r32 r41 r4X r42 r51 r5X r52 r61 r6X r62 r71 r7X r72 r81 r8X r82 r91 r9X r92 r101 r10X r102 r111 r11X r112 r121 r12X r122 r131 r13X r132
40  34  26  48  30  22  69  14  17  70  16  14  15  17  68  28  31  41  80  20  0   49  29  22  38  30  32  69   16   15   29   28   43   19   31   50   13   25   62
```

And that I can use in my php-template file.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values

Comment: How many different values are possible for each column?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Irrelevant comment?

Comment: @silkfire Non I'm serious: is there only 3 possible values par column '1', '2' and 'X' -- or more? As the expected result *seems* to be presented *one column per value*, this has an impact...

Comment: As for the duplication question. The solution there will not work as I have several column. It might be possible with the UNION solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the different solution. I have now done some testing on my data. I have done a query for 10000rows. And here is my findings.

Solution 1:

```
Select 'R01', r01, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r01
UNION 
Select 'R02', r02, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r02 
UNION
Select 'R03', r03, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r03 
UNION
Select 'R04', r04, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r04 
UNION
Select 'R05', r05, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r05 
UNION
Select 'R06', r06, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r06 
UNION
Select 'R07', r07, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r07 
UNION
Select 'R08', r08, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r08 
UNION
Select 'R09', r09, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r09 
UNION
Select 'R10', r10, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r10 
UNION
Select 'R11', r11, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r11 
UNION
Select 'R12', r12, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r12 
UNION
Select 'R13', r13, count(1) FROM `tips_rows` AS r INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id) WHERE user_id='27' group by r13
```

Takes ~0.1365s every time to query

Solution 2:

```
SELECT n,
       SUM(IF(r01 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r01',
       SUM(IF(r02 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r02',
       SUM(IF(r03 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r03',
       SUM(IF(r04 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r04',
       SUM(IF(r05 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r05',
       SUM(IF(r06 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r06',
       SUM(IF(r07 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r07',
       SUM(IF(r08 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r08',
       SUM(IF(r09 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r09',
       SUM(IF(r10 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r10',
       SUM(IF(r11 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r11',
       SUM(IF(r12 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r12',
       SUM(IF(r13 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r13'       
FROM `tips_rows` AS r
INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id)
JOIN (SELECT '1' AS n UNION SELECT '2' UNION SELECT 'X') S
WHERE user_id='27'
GROUP BY n;
```

Takes ~0.0997s first time to query. Could be cached in mysql query cache so second time takes ~0.0002s

Solution 3:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN r01 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r11,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r01 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r1X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r01 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r12,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r02 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r21,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r02 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r2X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r02 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r22,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r03 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r31,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r03 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r3X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r03 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r32,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r04 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r41,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r04 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r4X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r04 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r42,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r05 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r51,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r05 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r5X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r05 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r52,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r06 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r61,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r06 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r6X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r06 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r62,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r07 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r71,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r07 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r7X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r07 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r72,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r08 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r81,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r08 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r8X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r08 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r82,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r09 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r91,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r09 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r9X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r09 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r92,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r10 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r101,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r10 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r10X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r10 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r102,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r11 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r111,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r11 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r11X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r11 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r112,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r12 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r121,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r12 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r12X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r12 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r122,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r13 = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r131,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r13 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r13X,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r13 = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS r132
    FROM `tips_rows` AS r
    INNER JOIN tips_rows_users USING (row_id)
    WHERE user_id='27'
```

Takes ~0.0587s first and second time. After that 0.0002s for question after that.

I will go with solution 3. As it has the best worst case time. But it is strange that it takes two queries before cached.

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
Select 'R01', r01, count(1) from myTable group by r01
UNION 
Select 'R02', r02, count(1) from myTable group by r02 
UNION
Select 'R03', r03, count(1) from myTable group by r03 
UNION
Select 'R04', r04, count(1) from myTable group by r04
```

Comment: Not working. I am getting. #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: This will only come, if r01, r02, r03, r04 doesn't have the same data type, please check and confirm

Comment: @Kristoffer: 1 more thing, please paste the exact query which you are using along with the create table construct

Comment: Found the problem. You hade a typo on R03 the ' is on the wrong side of the ,

Comment: But this force me to query the 1.6 million big table several times. Would like to have it in one query.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only 4 columns and 3 possible values per column, and if you really want your result presented as "one column per value":

```
SELECT 'R01' AS 'Row', SUM(IF(r01 = 1, 1, 0)) as '1',
                       SUM(IF(r01 = 2, 1, 0)) as '2',
                       SUM(IF(r01 = 'X', 1, 0)) as 'X'
       FROM myTable
UNION  SELECT 'R02', SUM(IF(r02 = 1, 1, 0)) as '1',
                       SUM(IF(r02 = 2, 1, 0)) as '2',
                       SUM(IF(r02 = 'X', 1, 0)) as 'X'
       FROM myTable
UNION  SELECT 'R03', SUM(IF(r03 = 1, 1, 0)) as '1',
                       SUM(IF(r03 = 2, 1, 0)) as '2',
                       SUM(IF(r03 = 'X', 1, 0)) as 'X'
       FROM myTable

UNION  SELECT 'R04', SUM(IF(r04 = 1, 1, 0)) as '1',
                       SUM(IF(r04 = 2, 1, 0)) as '2',
                       SUM(IF(r04 = 'X', 1, 0)) as 'X'
       FROM myTable
```

Producing:

```
+------+----+----+---+
| ROW  | 1  | 2  | X |
+------+----+----+---+
| R01  | 6  | 1  | 2 |
| R02  | 2  | 6  | 1 |
| R03  | 3  | 2  | 4 |
| R04  | 4  | 3  | 2 |
+------+----+----+---+
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6376/2

---

If pivoting the result table is acceptable, the following query will perform *much* better:

```
SELECT n,
       SUM(IF(r01 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r01',
       SUM(IF(r02 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r02',
       SUM(IF(r03 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r03',
       SUM(IF(r04 = n, 1, 0)) AS 'r04'
FROM mytable JOIN (SELECT '1' AS n UNION SELECT '2' UNION SELECT 'X') S
GROUP BY n;
```

Resulting in:

```
+----+------+------+------+-----+
|    | R01  | R02  | R03  | R04 |
+----+------+------+------+-----+
| 1  |   6  |   2  |   3  |   4 |
| 2  |   1  |   6  |   2  |   3 |
| X  |   2  |   1  |   4  |   2 |
+----+------+------+------+-----+
```

Comment: It might not work. Because this will force me to query the mysql table with 1.6 million rows, several times.

Comment: @Kristoffer This is the price to paid as soon as you want to "pivot" the table. If you want "all in one line", *your* own solution is probably the best. If a "tabular" report rotated by 90° is acceptable, you could maybe simplify a little bit the query (see my edit above).