# Mysql select count values from a single column

Tags: mysql

A have a column named key - 1,1,2,2,2,2,3
Now i do it with 3 querys:

```
SELECT count(key) as k FROM `test` WHERE key=1
SELECT count(key) as k FROM `test` WHERE key=2
SELECT count(key) as k FROM `test` WHERE key=3
```

How to count in one query how many 1,2,3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the occurrences of DISTINCT values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/count-the-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use group by:

```
SELECT `key`, COUNT(*) FROM `test` GROUP BY `key`;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
select count(key) as K FROM test where key in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: otherwise you can use groupby

Answer (score 1):

This is another option:

```
SELECT sum(key=1) as k1, sum(key=2) as k2,sum(key=3) as k3 FROM `test`
```

you could also add a group by column if the values of key were part of some other group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  COUNT(Key) as K
        FROM 
        test 
        GROUP BY Key
```