# Counting occurances of values and printing them out

Tags: php, mysql, count, distinct

I know this question has been covered before I have read many answers and they all tell me how to write the SQL but not how to print out the results.

My dilemma is I have an orders table with a payment method field tha tlooks like this

```
OrderID     OrderNumber     PaymentMethod
 1234         a1b2c3          PayPal
 1235         a1b2c4          Account
 1236         a1b2c5          Account
 1237         a1b2c6          PayPal
 1238         a1b2c7          Account
 1239         a1b2c8          PayPal
 1230         a1b2c9          PayPal
```

I need to print out something like

**Number of PayPal payments: 4**

**Number of Account Payments: 3**

I have tried to use this answer

[MySQL: Count occurrences of distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

and I have this code

```
SELECT PaymentMethod,COUNT(*) as Payment FROM tablename GROUP BY PaymentMethod ORDER BY Payment DESC;
```

but how do I print this out?

Comment: Show the PHP code you already have for running that query. It should give you a result set like any other... don't understand the difficulty you are having? **Pseudo-code:** `while($row = $db->fetch()) { echo $row['PaymentMethod'].': '.$row['Payment']; }`

Comment: GO to PHP.net and see how to get result from your DB..
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php try that 1st example..

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is... That query gets the pair (payment, amount) that you're looking for. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$returned = mysqli_query("SELECT PaymentMethod,COUNT(distinct PaymentMethod) as Payment FROM tablename GROUP BY PaymentMethod ORDER BY Payment DESC;");
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($returned)){
    echo "Number of " . $data['PaymentMethod'] . ": " . $data[0] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Fixed it to make it more dynamic

Comment: This doesnt get the desired result, I need to print out the amount of each payment method

Comment: I think pairing the count and the distinct function like I just did in the edit might work.  Not 100% sure though

Comment: Count distinct + group ?

Comment: it doesnt work. I know how to print data normally. but this is not a normal SELECT and echo...at least not in my eyes

Comment: ok...the DISTINCT is not necessary, caused a bit of confusion...but thanks to your answer and a few tweaks I have got it working...thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**You should leave data representation to the VIEW.**

Having said that, this is how you can extract the data formatted in that way using purely MySQL:

```
SELECT concat('Number of ', paymentmethod ,' payments: ', count(*)) RESULT FROM t
GROUP BY paymentmethod
ORDER BY paymentmethod DESC
```

This results in:

```
|                        RESULT |
|-------------------------------|
|  Number of PayPal payments: 4 |
| Number of Account payments: 3 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44f1e/1).

Comment: Don't assume that everyone's working in an MVC environment...

Comment: Question is tagged as PHP so there is another processing level here which can/should handle that part of the process.

Comment: so? PHP is perfectly capable of sucking data out of a query and spitting it out to a display without having to slap on an MVC layer as well.

Comment: yeah I need to use PHP to print this out...but it doesnt appear like a normal SELECT, loop and echo

Comment: @MarcB Of course. And when spitting it out to a display that is the best time to format it... not while extracting it. That *display* you mention would be the VIEW, isn't it? I never mentioned MVC so far. Only you did :)