# SQL Count() column values

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following source table:

```
pid | code
----------
1      P2
2      P2
3      P3
4      P1
5      P2
6      P1
```

Now, I want to get the information how many times each code exists:

```
code | count
------------
P2      3
P1      2
P3      1
```

So I want to count the values from code column and assign it to the distinct set of available code values. Finally I want to order by count number.

Comment: Why do you all have brackets on Count?first of all its mysql and second its not a reserved word.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the occurrences of DISTINCT values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/count-the-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a2897/3/0):

```
SELECT t.code, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM MyTable t
GROUP BY t.code
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @testTable table (pid  int
                     ,code varchar(2)
)

insert into @testTable values (1, 'P2')
insert into @testTable values (2, 'P2')
insert into @testTable values (3, 'P3')
insert into @testTable values (4, 'P1')
insert into @testTable values (5, 'P2')
insert into @testTable values (6, 'P1')


SELECT CODE, COUNT(1) AS [COUNT]
FROM @testTable 
GROUP BY CODE
ORDER BY [COUNT] DESC
```

Comment: `[COUNT]` won't work.  You need to use the back tick instead.  Also `ORDER BY [COUNT] DESC` will not work, you need to use `ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC`.