# MySQL: Count occurrences of distinct values error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use code from the following old question:

[MySQL: Count occurrences of distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

My query is as follows:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT name,COUNT(*) as cnt FROM `table` GROUP BY name ORDER BY cnt DESC");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
var_dump($row);
```

In phpmyadmin this code will output all the name and COUNT columns. When I run `var_dump($row)` it will only have one row for me to work with (the first one, ie the one with the most occurrences), which I can't figure out why. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `mysqli_fetch_array`? Will make this question obsolete.

Comment: Did you made the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation on `mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

> Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both

As you found out, it does just that: it fetches a row.

Maybe you were expecting the behaviour of [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)?

> Fetches all result rows as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

Comment: Ugh, I forgot to throw in the while loop to iterate through all the rows. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.