# MySQL - I need to SELECT the highest umber in a column when there are multiple ID's

Tags: php, mysql, database

Take the following dataset:

```
id | Number
 1 | 6534
 1 | 765
 1 | 1234
 2 | 744
 2 | 6109
 3 | 333
 3 | 9888
 3 | 3112
 3 | 98432
```

I want to show the highest `Number` for each `id`.

So Like this:

```
id | Number
 1 | 6534
 2 | 6109
 3 | 98432
```

How can I do this with a `SELECT` statement?

I've already tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id, Number Desc
```

But this shows the entire dataset.

I'm not trying to get the number of occurences. I am trying to get the highest Number grouped by id but can't get it to work.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: have you search in Stack or tried yourself before posting your queries at there?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my post with what I've already tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Count occurrences of distinct values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

Comment: This question has been asked and answered a thousand times already. Next time, please undertake at least the most basic level of research before asking a question - e.g. consulting the manual and/or google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
Select id,max(Number) from Your_Table group by id
```

Your Query that you have tried, it will only order your Data table by the given parameters.

In the meantime, What i have proposed to you, will select the two columns you want to diplay (the id, and the maximum of the column "**Number**").

And the **group by** will help to the maximum of each group. That's why a group by id is the right clause to have the maximum of each group of Ids.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, MAX(Number) as Number FROM mytable GROUP BY id
```

Comment: @Aaqib1 please mark the answer as accepted answer so that people won't come back and answer again

Answer (score 0):

Most of time the id field is incremental but for your case you can use.

```
SELECT MAX(number) FROM `user` GROUP BY id
```

Where `number` is the column name from which you want to find `MAX`, and `user` is your table name.