# Count specific values. Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table that looks like:

```
field1 | field2
   1   | ready
   2   | ready
   1   | in_progress
   1   | ready
   2   | in_progress
```

How can i count number of "ready" fields for each field1?
For this example answer must be:

```
field1 | field2
   1   |   2
   2   |   1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1346345/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple filter and aggregation will do:

```
SELECT field1,
    COUNT(*) AS field2
FROM your_table
WHERE field2 = 'ready'
GROUP BY field1;
```

If you want to get those field1 values where count can be 0:

```
SELECT field1,
    SUM(field2 = 'ready') as field2
FROM your_table
GROUP BY field1;
```

`SUM(field2 = 'ready')` uses the fact that MySQL treats true as 1 and false as 0.

Comment: It's pretty basic SQL. Not much to explain I'm afraid :)

Comment: Well, i 've try to add your code to my query. It doesn't work still, cause i have a bit more sophisticated schema. Should i ask new question or edit this one?

Comment: @КириллТимофеев Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using simple aggregation using the [count()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) function:

```
select field1, count(field2) as field2
from yourtable
where field2 = 'ready'
group by field1
```

By filtering your data using a `WHERE = 'ready'` you then count the number of rows for each value in `field1`.