# how to query mysql data where 1 value appears more than another in a set time

Tags: mysql

Is there a way that I can retrieve data in a query where 1 value appears more than another in a set time.

My current query is:

```
SELECT * FROM location.track where time > date_sub(now(), interval 15 second)
```

which will pull the data i need for the past 15 seconds data value e.g.~

```
1, red
1, red
1, red
1,blue
1,yellow
2,red
2,green
3,orange
```

if red shows more than any other value in column 2 where column 1 value stays then same then only retrieve 1,red in the query?

The reason for wanting this query is I am using the data as a variable to colour a 1-100 html grid where if column 1 value matches the html table cell value then change colour of that cell to the colour linked with the mysql value.

Comment: You're looking for the `DISTINCT` clause.

Comment: you can try using the case when while selecting the data in your query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Count occurrences of distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

Comment: `select color, count(*) from table group by color order by count(*) desc limit1`

Comment: cwallenpoole I dont need to count the occurrences I did think about trying it that way but i need it so that where the number value is the same but the colour value is differs extract the colour that appears the most.