# MySQL: Count occurrences of distinct values for each row

Tags: mysql

Based on an example already given, I would like to ask my further question.
[MySQL: Count occurrences of distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

example db

```
id         name
-----      ------
1          Mark
2          Mike
3          Paul
4          Mike
5          Mike
6          John
7          Mark
```

expected result

```
name       count
-----      -----
Mark       2
Mike       3
Paul       1
Mike       3
Mike       3
John       1
Mark       2
```

In my opinion 'GROUP BY' doesn't help.
Thank you very  much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Count occurrences of distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

Comment: @WhatsThePoint it is not  duplicate. Please check the expected output is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest approach would be using [`Count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) as [Window Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) over a partition of `name`; but they are available only in [MySQL 8.0.2 and onwards](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/).

However, another approach is possible using a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html). In a sub-select query (Derived Table), we will identify the counts for each unique `name`. Now, we simply need to join this to the main table, to show counts against each name (while not doing a grouping on them):

```
SELECT 
  t1.name, 
  dt.total_count 
FROM your_table AS t1 
JOIN 
(
 SELECT name, 
        COUNT(*) AS total_count 
 FROM your_table
 GROUP BY name
) AS dt ON dt.name = t1.name 
ORDER BY t1.id
```

---

If MySQL 8.0.2+ is available, the solution would be less verbose:

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS total_count 
FROM your_table
```