# Sequentially number each occurrence of distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I've got a list of job numbers and associated customer codes. Sometimes there is more than one customer per job number. Using the below link, I incorporated the answer to get the results showing the total count of occurrences of each job number as represented here:

[MySQL: Count occurrences of distinct values for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103519/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values-for-each-row)

Code:

```
SELECT CR_CONTRACT_MASTER1_V.Job_Number, CR_CONTRACT_MASTER1_V.CUSTOMER_CODE,
    COUNT(CR_CONTRACT_MASTER1_V.Job_Number) OVER (PARTITION BY CR_CONTRACT_MASTER1_V.Job_Number)

From CR_CONTRACT_MASTER1_V

GROUP BY CR_CONTRACT_MASTER1_V.Job_Number, CR_CONTRACT_MASTER1_V.CUSTOMER_CODE
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Results:

```
   21-0138  NULT01      3
   21-0138  WASAN       3
   21-0138  WMRENEW     3
   21-0204  AMA12       2
   21-0204  GSOI3       2
```

I don't actually know anything about what I'm doing here, I just started doing some SQL stuff a couple of days ago. Is there a way to count each occurrence in sequential order to look more like this?

```
   21-0138  NULT01      1
   21-0138  WASAN       2
   21-0138  WMRENEW     3
   21-0204  AMA12       1
   21-0204  GSOI3       2
```

I used SSMS to write this query

EDIT:
Can this be arranged so that a specific customer code is listed first?

In this example data results, I want "NULT01" customer code to always be listed first like this:

```
   21-0138  NULT01      1
   21-0138  WASAN       2
   21-0138  WMRENEW     3
   21-0204  NULT01      1
   21-0204  GSOI3       2
```

The results would always show "NULT01" before any other customer codes regardless of alphabetical order.

Comment: Looks like you are asking for `row_number() over(partition by Job_number order by Customer_Code)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `COUNT()`:

```sql
SELECT
    Job_Number,
    CUSTOMER_CODE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Job_Number) AS rn
FROM CR_CONTRACT_MASTER1_V
GROUP BY
    Job_Number,
    CUSTOMER_CODE
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_CODE LIKE 'UNHI%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
    3;
```

Comment: @John I have a serious tag reading dyslexia problem lately, mistaking many SQL questions for MySQL when in fact they are not.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, ROW_NUMBER seems to have done the trick! Is there a way to prioritize which customer code gets listed first? For example, if the customer code is "UNHI", can I get that one to always be listed as the first one?

Comment: Please see edited post above showing desired results.

Comment: Sort using a `CASE` expression.