# How to count the number of messages per user in php

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table users with (id,name) and user_messages(m_id,user_id,msg_seen) and now i want to count the number of messages per user(like whatsapp)how to write a sql query for that? i have bulded it for a user who has looged in and now i want to show the number of messages per user?I mean i want to show me the amount of messagges which were send by other users

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Count occurrences of distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"SELECT COUNT(m_id) FROM user_messages WHERE user_id != $_SESSION['user_id']"
```

Comment: I mean i want to show me the amount of messagges which were send by other users