# Count and GROUP values from a CASE expression

Tags: sql, t-sql, view, distinct-values

Trying to count the total number of wins and total times a horse finished in the top 6 and `GROUP` by the order of favouritism in a horse racing market.

I am referencing this answer since it is looking for a similar outcome [Count the occurrences of DISTINCT values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/count-the-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

I have tried this expression but when executed, it returns the same number in both case columns

ie;

```
SPFav   WinsByFavouritism   PlaceByFavouritism
1       4143                4143
2       3963                3963
3       3853                3853
```

This is the code I am running - what is causing this?

```
SELECT SPFav, 

COUNT(CASE WHEN FinishingPosition = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as WinsByFavouritism,
COUNT(CASE WHEN FinishingPosition <= 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PlaceByFavouritism

FROM [NRaceHistory].[dbo].[EachWayBetting]

GROUP BY SPFav 

ORDER BY SPFav ;
```

Comment: I don't see a `DISTINCT` in your attempt, however, you only have 2 different `DISTINCT` values from your `CASE` expression, `1` and `0`. Sample data and expected results will help us help you here. Perhaos you should be returning the horse's name for the `THEN` and npt have an `ELSE`? Complete blind guess though.

Comment: Yes, but it is not the horse name I am interested in, I want to count how many times the SPFav 1,2,3 etc win races

Comment: So what *is* the `DISTINCT` value you want to count? Then just do what I said above, but use that instead of Horse Name. Like I said, it was a complete blind guess as we have no sample data or expected results here.

Comment: `COUNT(0)` is counted.  `COUNT(null-value)` is not counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the first comment this would give the following possible solution.

**Sample data**

```
create table EachWayBetting
(
  SPFav int,
  FinishingPosition int
);

insert into EachWayBetting (SPFav, FinishingPosition) values
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 2),
(1, 9),
(2, 7),
(2, 8),
(2, 2),
(2, 1);
```

**Solution**

```
SELECT SPFav,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN FinishingPosition = 1 THEN 1 END) as WinsByFavouritism,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN FinishingPosition <= 6 THEN 1 END) as PlaceByFavouritism
FROM EachWayBetting
GROUP BY SPFav
ORDER BY SPFav
```

**Result**

```
SPFav WinsByFavouritism PlaceByFavouritism
----- ----------------- ------------------
1     1                 3
2     1                 2
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=334431b7d52c25820bb048a9ecfe69a8)

Comment: That's right, using `count` is counting the `0` in the case expression - removing else (or changing `count` to `sum`) returns the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should replace COUNT in your query with SUM. i.e. it should be:

```
SELECT SPFav, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN FinishingPosition = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as WinsByFavouritism,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FinishingPosition <= 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PlaceByFavouritism
FROM [NRaceHistory].[dbo].[EachWayBetting]
GROUP BY SPFav 
ORDER BY SPFav;
```