# MySQL count multiple GroupBy

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like this

```
id  otherid name    
1   123     banana
2   123     banana
3   123     banana
4   456     grape
5   456     grape
6   789     orange
7   111     banana
```

How can I get output like this: (with MySQL query)

```
name    count
banana  2
grape   1
orange  1
```

Comment: Show us the query you tried, which isn't working yet. Show us the google search results you relied on when trying to come up with a solution.

Comment: Looks like ```COUNT(DISTINCT otherid) GROUP BY name```.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the occurrences of DISTINCT values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/count-the-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

Comment: sorry @FanoFN , thats not answer for my needs

Comment: I actually agree. The exact link that I post as duplicate doesn't address the issue that you're having but I'm more than sure that this has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  f.`name`,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (f.`otherid`)) 
FROM
  `fruits` f 
GROUP BY f.`name`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  `name`, COUNT(*)
FROM
  write_you_table_name
GROUP BY
  `name`,`otherid`
```

Comment: Your query won't give him the expected result.

Comment: @Asgar Why not work? I checked It is working properly

Comment: if you read the question properly, you'll see that the expected output is grouped by name along with distinct otherid. Your query will give the total counts group by name

Comment: ok but when it group_by with `name` and `otherid` then result is coming with along name and along otherid. it's working both distinct and also multiple group_by.

Comment: still your edited query also won't work. Check all data and try again

Answer (score 0):

Using `distinct` in the `count` function is recommended. But if you prefer not to using it, try this:

```
select name,count(*) from 
(select name from fruit group by name,otherid) t
group by name;
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT name , count(*) as count FROM `tb_stock` GROUP BY other_id

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).